# What is the proper OOP architecture for Rust?

Tags: oop, rust

I have a program that written in python and uses classes.
i wanna convert the same structure to Rust but we don't have classes in rust instead we have (impl & strcut). so that makes me confuse that how can implement the same OOP structure as python in Rust !

Please bring an example for the architecture in Rust so i can have it as reference.

i've tried reading this tutorial but i didn't get what i want.
https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/object-orientation.html

My existing program example:

file: main.py

```py
import my_lib

class main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('main > init')

    def start(self):
        my_lib.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

file: /lib/my_lib.py

```py
    def run():
        print('running...')
```

Comment: I don't see much of OOP in your example. I would say, that rust is partly OOP, at least in that sens, that there are methods (there is data and that data brings it's own processing). But you do not have inheritance in rust.

Comment: @chpio im sorry but i am very new to Rust and everything sound different. So what is your example of a proper architecture for Rust. appreciate if you comment a simple example here so i can take it as my reference. Thanks

Comment: "i've tried reading this tutorial but i didn't get what i want." What do you want?

Comment: "how can implement the same OOP structure as python in Rust" You can't, what is the point in copy & pasting the python code if you want rust code? Rust is not python.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you come from one language to another which is very different, the least productive thing to do is to try to translate code 1:1. Learn Rust on its own terms first, follow all the tutorials and write code that *provides the same result*, not code that tries to imitate another language. Eventually when you know Rust well enough you will see the patterns and similarities, or know why something can't be translated 1:1 and what pattern to apply instead.

Comment: @deceze that's what i wanted to write :)

Comment: @chpio im not trying to say python is good or i want the exact same thing. I'm beginner dude (no need to fight). All I'm asking is just how should i start, the rust is different than other languages and i have experience in python that i can put an example... . if i knew Rust well, never asked here!

Comment: There is no inheritance in your Python code, so it's not strictly speaking OOP. The tutorial you want is [this one](https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/2-structs-enums-lifetimes.html#structs).

Comment: @deceze Thanks for your gentle highlights. Do you think is this enough to only follow [this Tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code example you give doesn't make use of many object-oriented features, but it's not too hard to translate into Rust:

file: main.rs

```
mod my_lib; // This instructs Rust to look for `my_lib.rs` and import it as `my_lib`.
mod main {
    pub fn init() {
        println!("main > init");
    }

    pub fn start() {
        super::my_lib::run() // We have to add super:: to talk about things that were imported in the parent module rather than the `main` module itself, like `my_lib` 
    }
}

fn main() { // This is the function that starts your program. It's always called `main`.
    main::init()
}
```

file: my_lib.rs

```
pub fn run() {
    println!("running...")
}
```

Notably, this isn't quite equivalent to your python code, because `main` is a module instead of a class. If you intend to use its `self` instance to store data or any persistent state, the example would look different (`main` would be a `struct`, and its methods would be in an `impl` block.) I can edit my answer if that's closer to what you're looking for.